# How can i calculate where the non transparent part of an image starts and ends with PHP?

Tags: php, transparency, imagemagick, gdlib

Here's a question: let's say we have a png image 200x200 that is transparent and there is a shape that starts at x,y (50,50) and has a width of 50px and height 20px.

Is there any way with PHP (gdlib or imagemagick) that i could get the position of the shape relative to the image size? For the example given the script should return (x1=50, y1=70, x2=100, y2=70)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does it mean "a shape that starts at"? For example for an ellipse, you want to find a top left corner of a rectangle which will cover the entire ellipse?

If yes, than you can loop through every pixel of an image (`getpixel` would give you the color of a pixel) from top to bottom searching for the topmost and bottommost point which is not transparent (ending the loop when found). It will be your *y1* and *y2* points. Then, you do the same thing looping from left to right *inside y1 - y2 range* to find *x1* and *x2*.

This is probably not very optimized, so you may want to imagine a better algorithm. For example, if the image is 300×200 pixels, you may search for topmost point by:

1. Seeing if there is an object at the row 100 (height / 2).
2. If so, looking for a row 50 (100 / 2).
3. If line 50 contains object, then you scan the line 25 (50 / 2).
4. Let's imagine line 25 is transparent. You may need to look at line 38 (25 / 2 + 25).
5. If line 38 is not transparent, you may look at the line 32 ([25 / 2] / 2 + 25).
6. ...

By the way, let's say when you scanned line 25, you found a non-transparent point at the coordinates *x = 74, y = 50*. Now, when searching the same way for the leftmost point, instead of starting from *x = 150* (width / 2), you can start from 37 (74 / 2), since you already know that there **is** an object at *x = 74*.

Comment: Hi, thnx for the really useful answer. I'm interested in a rectangle for start. Doesn't this method (looping through every pixel) have too much overhead?

Comment: Well, I imagine there are more optimized ways of doing things. Now, if you stop searching for topmost pixel once found, or for a rightmost pixel, etc., it already optimizes things quite a bit. I edited my question to include a suggestion of optimization (ie. to reduce overhead).